# In a dapp application who listens to events?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, events

In a dapp application who listens to events? the geth node or my node.js component (backend component?
[image]

How can I implement the listen function in web3.js?

Answer (score 0):

Just like all the others outputs, Web3.js handles the events.

Comment: yes but what is the process? The backend requests new blocks from the geth, extracts events from them and selects the necessary ones. Is it correct?
How can I implement the listen function in web3.js? is it more correct to use myContract.events.MyEvent () orweb3.eth.subscribe ('logs',…)?